# Form validation with Javascript and "undefined" problem

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I build form validation with the code below. It`s work but If  some of required field is filled var msg contains undefinied value.

For example if username is filled but password not var msg contains
'undefinied'
Field is requred

How to avoid that ?

Here is the code:

```
var i = 0;
var error_msg = [];
var msg = ;

var errors = {
    'username' : 'Field is required',
    'password' : 'Field is requred',
    'city'     : 'City is required'
    etc...... etc... 
};

for(var x in errors) {
    i++;
    if(!$('#'+x).val()) {
        error_msg[i] = errors[x];
    }   
}
if(error_msg.length > 0) {

    for(var x = 0; x < errors_msg.length; x++) {

        msg += errors_msg[x] +"\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Could someone please explain to me why people use Jquery for such simple things, I just don't understand why...  For form validation plain old javascript would probably be a lot easier to understand/maintain/debug/write.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, besides the obviously broken `for in` loop and the missing assignment of `msg`.

This is your *actual* problem:

```
var error_msg = []; // new empty array

for(var x in errors) {
    i++; // i starts with 1 this way!
    // other code
}
```

So you're never setting the `0`th  index. Yes arrays start with index `0`. So if you set an index that's bigger then the current length of the array, JavaScript will insert the missing elements before that index.

In your case, JavaScript will insert the default `undefined` at index `0` since the first index you set is `1`.

**Fixing**

```
var error_msg = [];
for(var x in errors) {
    if (errors.hasOwnProperty(x)) { // see note below
        if(!$('#'+x).val()) {
            error_msg.push(errors[x]); // append to the array
        }
    }
}

var msg = error_msg.join('\n'); // no need for an if, will be empty if there are no errors.
```

**Note:** See [hasOwnProperty](http://bonsaiden.github.com/JavaScript-Garden/#hasownproperty)

Answer (score 4):

One thing I see is:

```
var msg = ;
```

Should(could) be

```
var msg = "";
```

Did you also try to:

```
alert($('#'+x).length);
```

To see if jQuery finds the element? (if it returns 0, then its not found)

Comment: `alert($('#'+x));` will **always** give you `[object Object]`, unless you forgot to load jQuery - you're better off with `$('#'+x).length` and `console.log`. Using Firequery with Firefox for best effect.

Answer (score 0):

This is not your problem, and so this is not really an answer, but comments don't support code very well:

```
if(error_msg.length > 0) {

    for(var x = 0; x < errors_msg.length; x++) {

        msg += errors_msg[x] +"\n";
    }
}
```

For future reference, you never need to write that code:

```
msg = errors_msg.join('\n');
```

does the same thing.